# EF 6.2.0 (Code First) doesn't create database without any exceptions and errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6.2.0 Code First to create a database based on my model.

There were a few exceptions that I fixed. But now, when I run the application (ASP.NET MVC) it will be executed correctly without any exceptions. But I still don't see a created database on the SQL Server databases list.
I have no idea what's wrong with this. I get no exceptions and no errors.

This is my HomeController (Index action method):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ShopStatusService shopStatusService = new ShopStatusService();
        shopStatusService.Insert(new Model.Models.ShopStatus
        {
            Id = 1,
            Title = "Example"
        });
        return View();
    }
```

The Insert() method of ShopStatusService is like this:

```
    public long Insert(ShopStatus entity)
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.Set<ShopStatus>().Add(entity);
            SaveContext();
            return entity.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

and my DatabaseContext:

```
    public class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
    public MyDbContext() : base("MyDb") { }
    static MyDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AbarbazarDatabaseContext, Migration.Configuration>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ShopStatus> ShopStatuses { get; set; }
    // and other tables.....
  }
```

Comment: And `MyDb` connection string is ...? Most likely it's using the LocalDB (default).

Comment: did you run `Update-Database` to apply pending migrations to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It was missing the connection string in Web.Config.**

Answer (score 0):

```
public ZSZDbContext():base("name=myDb"){}
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());           
}
```

you can try this code
or   check your connecctionstring

Comment: if your database is created,please add Database.SetInitializer<ZSZDbContext>(null);